# Client side validation on button click before AJAX request

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, unobtrusive-validation

I'm using MVC 4 and I want to be able to validate a single row, from a collection of rows in a table, to ensure that the fields are entered correctly and pass validation.

The Attributes are correctly applied on the model, for example:

```
[Required]
[MaxLength(50)]
[MinLength(5)]
public string Name {get; set;}
```

Now, on the client side - how do I enable client side validation before calling an AJAX method?

To add more complications - I have a button where you can dynamically add a row to the table, fill out fields and finally hit the update button, which will do a POST via ajax. But before this post, I want to validate that particular row on client side.

how can I do this?

thank you

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As long as you're implementing the validation helpers in your View, this is actually really simple.

```
var form = $('#form');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse(form);
form.validate();

if (form.valid()) {
    .... ajax stuff
}
```

Call the above before initiating the http request and it will make sure that your form is validated.

Comment: thanks! So this almost works. I have a problem where a string is required but must have a min of 5 chars and a max of 100. if I enter < 5, I don't get any validation errors on the client side but DO on the server side. When I enter nothing in the textbox, the validation on clientside works. thoughts? This is what is being spat out on the DOM: <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="WorkItem[0].Title" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>

Comment: Hmm, have you tried using `[StringLength(50, MinimumLength=5)]`?

Comment: Okay, as this is a different issue, create a new question and include your view code, your controller action and your revised JavaScript :) I'd appreciate the accept if my answer solved your "no validation" issue!

Comment: actually, you are correct. that worked - I was using something else!

Comment: ok, how about just validating for a particular row rather than the whole form itself? the row is a table row with a ValidateMessageFor

Comment: I would suggest loading a partial view that contains its own form.

Comment: agreed. but any other way without it?

Comment: I'm assuming you have basically just got some textboxes underneath your table which emulate the way a row would look, what you can do is add the validation yourself using the unobtrusive validation library in JavaScript. It can be a bit tedious, but it's not that bad if you only need to do it for a few fields.